# Test site pages go to main site

Tags: permalinks, pages, redirect, htaccess, testing

I have a test site installed on www.mydomain.com/testsite.

The problem I have is that if I type in the url www.mydomain.com/testsite/about I get redirected to www.mydomain.com/about.

My page for my test site gives me the permalink: www.mydomain.com/testsite/about

If I click View Page from the page editing screen in the dashboard, I get redirected to www.mydomain.com/about instead of being sent to the permalink.

My htaccess file is located in my root folder and is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<Files delete.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your htaccess file seems to be a little off.

I would suggest the first part of the file should look like the following...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testsite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /testsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And that you store it in the 'testsite' folder not the root.

Comment: but if I move it to my testsite folder, my main site won't function properly. Is it safe to have two htaccess files in two different places?

Comment: Yes - as long as they don't contradict one another.